# Azure web app is throwing an error on put requests

Tags: azure, put, azure-web-app-service

I have an application that includes a JS client with an ASP.Net server, and is published as an Azure web app.

The application is working smoothly on local environment, however, when browsing to the web app, any PUT request returns with failure - error 500. That's despite the fact that the posted data is indeed saved successfully. Also when remote debugging the web app, the code is executed completely with no errors.

Looking at the diagnostic logs, I can see that the request fails on an IIS module called: ManagedPipelineHandler.

This is the error details:
 [image: error details]

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you are seeing HTTP 503 and have enabled [Failed request tracing logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-diagnostic-logs), please check the logs for HTTP 503. The one highlighted by you is for HTTP 500. It will give you detailed information as to where the request is failing.

Comment: Actually, I just see now that the client gets error 500 and in the trace log I see the same error as yesterday. Probably the 503 was only a temporary status... but the issue still persist.